# Adding color with VBA to an entire excel row

Tags: vba, excel

I want to add `n` rows starting from A4 cell.

My A3 row is blue, so adding rows below it will add all blue rows.

This is my code:

```
Range("A4:A4").Select
Dim lRow As Long
For lRow = 4 To 14
    Cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    Selection.EntireRow.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove        
Next lRow
```

I got an error saying:

> "Object required"

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

```
Range("A4:A4").Select
Dim lRow As Long
For lRow = 4 To 14
    Cells(lRow,1).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    Selection.EntireRow.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove        
Next lRow
```

You used `Cell` which doesn't mean anything to VBA. Use `Cells([row],[column])` or even just `Rows(lRow).EntireRow...`

Also though, you're selecting a single cell (`Range("A4:A4").Select`) and this never changes, so only `A4` would ever get a row inserted - is this what you want?

Edit: Without using `.Select`:

```
Dim myCell as Range
Dim lRow As Long

Set myCell = Range("A4")
For lRow = 4 To 14
    Cells(lRow,1).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    myCell.EntireRow.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove        
Next lRow
```

Comment: thx it works with:  Range("A" & lRow).Select just at the beginning of the loop and then....       Selection.EntireRow.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove    _     Cells(lRow, 1).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

Comment: @albert - please see my edit, as it's best practice to [avoid using `.Select`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Answer (score 1):

Am i missing something here? Why is everyone looping?

```
Range("A4:A14").EntireRow.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("A4:A14").EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub testing()

Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

'Range("A4:A4").Select

lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 4 To 14
    Range("A" & i & ":" & "A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 5

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Sub testing()

Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")


lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 4 To 14
    Range("A" & i & ":" & "A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
  
Next i

End Sub